# How to create an online, self-paced training for software?

Tags: video, presentations

I'm training people to use a PowerPoint add-in and have created a series of videos for that purpose. I'd like to cut the videos into smaller steps and allow people to follow along the steps and "tick them off" on a checklist.

Does somebody have a recommendation for a website, wordpress plugin or similar to setup the course and include the videos?

For example I would chose the course "How to tune the PowerPoint Master?". Then I presentated with 10 steps:

1) Intro 
2) File-nameing
...
10) Conclusion

Each of the steps might have sub steps etc.

Comment: Questions seeking product or service recommendations are off topic at Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Udemy](http://www.udemy.com) provides classes in that format. Classes are broken into a sequence of videos and the site shows a student which videos he/she has completed so far. An instructor can charge a fee for the class or offer it for free and there are many free classes on the site. There are [free and paid PowerPoint tutorials offered at the site](https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?ref=home&q=powerpoint); you could register for some of the free ones to see the Udemy class format.